# React native moving screen to active screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

while in DetailFamilyScreen and onpress ListItem other family member then move to same DetailFamilyScreen with different parameters
how do I switch to the DetailFamilyScreen page while on the DetailFamilyScreen

```
const DetailFamilyScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
const item = navigation.state.params.item;

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

const getResult = async id => {
    setLoading(true)
    const response = await server.get(`/person/${item._id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setResult(response.data);
        console.log(response.data)
        setLoading(false)
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getResult();
  }, []);

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title='Add Member' onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('AddPerson', { item:item })}} />
            <FlatList
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={result}
                keyExtractor={(person) => person._id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                    <ListItem
                        title={item.name}
                        subtitle={item._id}
                        bottomDivider
                        chevron
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DetailFamilyScreen', { item:item })}
                    />
                );
                }}
            />
    </View>
);}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QESRM.png)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Could you add more info and  some relevant code?

Comment: while on on DetailFamily

onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DetailFamily', { item:item })}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, I think it makes more sense to update your state instead of calling navigate.

So you can do something like this:

```
const DetailFamilyScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(route.params?.item);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getResult();
  }, [item]);

  // ...
  onPress={() => {
    setItem(item);
  }}
  // ...
```

You can also set a default value if necessary:

`route.params?.someParam ?? {name: "test", etc...};`

So the component will re-render with the new item and your `getResult` will use the new item to set the `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you really want to do but if you want to navigate to the same screen with new parameters, you have to use navigate.push instead of navigation.navigate (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/).